# how to make script to ask user for network details & then to apply those in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, networking

I want two scripts one where I collect the Network information and then second where I use that information to create and apply the net-plan configuration. I want to achieve this using ONLY shell script.

The script should simply ask for IP, Subnet or CIDR, Gateway & 2 DNS Server IP's. At the same time, it should validate the information entered by user.

The second script is to create a netplan coding. This is a yaml file that can be used to configure the network, gathered from [How to Assign Static IP Address on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - LinuxTechi](https://www.linuxtechi.com/assign-static-ip-address-ubuntu-20-04-lts/). Example file,

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
  version: 2
```

Can this be done? Can someone help? I want to use it into an automated installation of **Ubuntu 20.04**

Below is what I'm working on, I know it's not complete and may be an awful wrong way of doing it, but that's why I need help :P

---shell

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli device status | awk '{print $1}' | sed '1d' | sed '$d' > /tmp/itic-ls-networks
echo "None" >> /tmp/itic-ls-networks
sum3="cat /tmp/itic-ls-networks"

            nmcli device status | awk '{print $1}' | sed '1d' | sed '$d' | wc -l > /tmp/itic-total-networks
            sum1=$(cat /tmp/itic-total-networks)
            sum2=`expr $sum1 + 1`

            var1=1
            for sum2 in $var1
            do 
                nmcli device status | awk '{print $1}' | sed '1d' | sed '$d' | sed 's/^/ '$var1')     /' >> /tmp/itic-networks
            done
Please enter the IP Address
read itic-ip-cidr
num = `expr match $itic-ip-cidr [.]`
if num != 3
then
    echo "please enter the correct IP v4 address & the CIDR Value"
```

---

I'm still working on it and I'm stuck real bad and don't know if I'm doing it right or not.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it is very difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Can you edit your post to include sample input (what the scripts should ask the user for) and describe by what mechanism you want to apply the information gathered? Also, please indicate what you have already tried, and where you ran into difficulties, otherwise contributors will likely propose solutions that don't suit your needs or that you already tried and failed with.

Comment: @AdminBee It should simply ask IP, Subnet or CIDR, Gateway & 2 DNS Server IP's. at the same time it should validate the information entered by user. and second script to create a netplan coding to the information provided by user in the fist script.

Comment: As I stated, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/587875/edit) your post to include that information. Also, what do you mean by "create a netplan coding"? What OS flavor and version are you using? What network management system are you using? And most importantly, please show us what you have tried so far so that contributors don't run off in the wrong direction.

Comment: @AdminBee Please check now and let me know if there is anything i can do to improve the question, I hope that its fair enough information because that's all I have. but still let me know if you need anything and I will try my best to provide that information,

Comment: Yes, I think now people can work with the question and try to help you.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter IP Address: "
read ip
valid_ip=0
if [[ "$ip" =~ ^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$ ]]; then
        echo "Valid IP: $ip";
        valid_ip=1;
else
        echo "Invalid IP: $ip";
fi

echo -n "Read CIDR: "
read cidr
valid_cidr=1
if [[ "$cidr" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$cidr" -le 32 ]]; then
    echo "Valid CIDR: $cidr";
    valid_cidr=1;
else
    echo "Invalid CIDR: $cidr";
fi

#If both are valid, print them out in the form ip/cidr
if [[ "$valid_ip" -eq 1 && $valid_cidr -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo "Valid"
   echo "$ip/$cidr"
fi
```

Gateway and DNS are the same as IP just in a new variable.

After you have all the variables, printing a yaml file for the netplan part is easy enough.

---

regex for IP from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp